# Weblogic giving license error for only one managed server

Tags: weblogic

Hi i am running weblogic 8.1 on a unix server.  I currently had 4 managed servers running fine and started two more today.  Unfortunately people started getting denied with a "The server is not licensed for this operation.connect rejected, the server license allows connections from only 5 unique IP addresses.  When i check my license.bea file it appears to be for only a developer license, which would make sense.  The part I'm confused on is why my other 4 managed servers never receive this message.  Don't they all use the same license file?  They are all in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Weblogic install is unlicensed, or at least you haven't installed the license file. You need to stick the file **license.bea** in the BEA_HOME directory.

The 5 IP limit is always enforced by Weblogic when running in development mode.

It's also advisable to use a reverse web proxy in front of the Weblogic managed servers.